# Feature Importances for Isolation Forest?

Tags: anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

Is there a way to dig in to sklearn's [Isolation Forest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html) algorithm to understand *why* data is scored as an inlier or outlier? I see that you can produce a score with decision_function (for data used to fit the model), or with score_samples (for additional data).

I would like to be able to see what feature (or combination of features) were used to create scores. How is the tree constructed, and what data makes up the isolated leaf nodes? For instance, is there anything equivalent to [Tree Interpreter](https://github.com/andosa/treeinterpreter)?

Comment: If you look at the provided code in the link there is a function `decision_function(self, X)` which estimates these, going though the code you can interpret the results then.

Comment: Sorry, I may need more help. I'm looking at decision_function and it looks to me like that just returns `self.score_samples(X) - self.offset_` . Digging in to `score_samples`, that only returns a single score.  I'd like to be able to open up `score_samples` to be able to see the depths, and compare that to that to the _average_path_length.

Comment: If I were answering the question, I would love to see a toy problem to attack.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this is possible, although the solution I suggest would not have worked in 2018 at the time this was originally asked.

[SHAP](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package has support for scikit-learn Isolation forests since [2019](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/pull/784), (that same thread for a discussion of precisely *what* it is SHAP is explaining in the case of an Isolation Forest).

I will give you a concrete example (you will see why that is funny in a minute...). I picked a random dataset for this, [properties of samples of concrete](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/concrete+compressive+strength). I thought it might be interesting to see what an anomalous sample of concrete looks like, and *why* it might be considered unusual.

We read in the dataset, fit an Isolation forest, and then explain with the `shap.TreeExplainer` (I will include my complete code at the end).

### SHAP summary plot

[image: summary plot]

Here is the summary plot. Remember, with the isolation forest in scikit-learn, -1 corresponds to anomalies and +1 to the inliers. We should think of low SHAP values as pushing us towards outlier and high SHAP values as pushing us towards inlier.
If we look at slag, we can see that high feature values of slag correspond to a low SHAP value. So we might start to think that samples containing large amounts of slag are unusual. The coarseagg feature is quite interesting - we have high and low feature values for coarseagg corresponding to low SHAP values, and then medium feature values (purple colour) corresponding to higher SHAP values.

We can see this non linear relationship below with a scatter plot `shap.plots.scatter(shap_values[:,"coarseagg"])`.

[image: scatter]

### Explain individual examples

We can explain individual concrete samples. Here is a *force plot* of one of the **least anomalous samples**.

[image: least]

And here is one of the **most anomalous samples** (outlier).

[image: most]

### Python Code

***Notes**:*

- The SHAP documentation can be hard to follow, with some examples no longer working.
- If you are running this in a Jupyter notebook you may need to explicitly run `shap.initjs()` at the top of each cell which contains a JS plot otherwise the plot won't render.

```
%pip install shap
import pandas as pd
import shap
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
# It was easier for me to read in the dataset as a csv which I found on somebody's github
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/master/concrete.csv")
X = df.copy()
clf = IsolationForest(random_state=0).fit(X)
exp = shap.TreeExplainer(clf, X) 
shap_values = exp(X) 
#Summary plot
shap.initjs()
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X)
#Scatter plot
shap.plots.scatter(shap_values[:,"coarseagg"])
#Force plot of one of the inliers
shap.initjs()
N=624
shap.force_plot(exp.expected_value, shap_values.values[N],features =X.iloc[N,:] ,feature_names =X.columns)
#Force plot of one of the outliers
shap.initjs()
N=42
shap.force_plot(exp.expected_value, shap_values.values[N],features =X.iloc[N,:] ,feature_names =X.columns)
```